# Raspberrypi wont boot after installing any package

Tags: boot, noobs

I am new to pi. I setup my pi from NOOBS 2.8.2. My problem is that whenever I install any package by 
`sudo apt-get install <PACKAGE NAME>` command the package gets installed but when I try to run my device for the next time the device will not boot.

I thought this was my SD card or power supply problem but the device will work normal if no any package is installed. I tried many times by installing fresh NOOBS to my SD card, but the problem repeats.

---UPDATE---
Well it seems that there is problem with NOOBS. Everything works fine after installing raspbian without it.

Comment: This sounds extremely strange, and it's certainly not in line with expectations. Can I ask what packages you have tried to install this way, and if you have done anything at all besides installing a package before you try to reboot your pi?

Comment: `any package` - really? any at all? How many times have you done this? which packages did you install on each occasion?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I initially i tried installing motion, now I try to install gedit, the problem is same.

Comment: @Bex all I have done is updated the apt and then tried to install the package. I tried to install motion for which the problem occured then for test I tried to install gedit, I faced the same problem

Comment: how much "free space" do you have on your SD card before you apt-get? did you try a different SD card (regardless if it works somewhere else)

Comment: @JaromandaX I have not used other SD card. My SD card is Samsung evo+ 32 GB micro SD card. I have 23GB free space on root partition

Comment: so, the output of `df` outputs that the partition mounted on `/`'s usage is less than 50% or something (that seems to be a LOT of used space for a fresh install)

Comment: @JaromandaX is it necessary to use another SD card?

Comment: I don't know, it was a *suggestion* - what is the output of `df` before you install any other packages

Comment: do you know what `df` is?

Comment: yes I do @JaromandaX now that I have installed raspbian without NOOBS its working perfectly fine.

Comment: I think perhaps you ran out of disk space

Comment: @JaromandaX well I don't think its the disk space issue because offline installs were working fine even for large applications. I think its some issue about reading SD card because I could see at my monitor giving message PIO read time out, canot switch card to high speed mode and so on

Answer (score 1):

Booting from a fresh flashed image and before installing packets you should do:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then reboot and install your software packet.